# Range de um dataframe - Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe, columns

Galera, eu tenho um dataframe onde uma das minhas colunas é um número de chassi.
A partir dessa coluna eu preciso criar outra com os últimos 8 dígitos desse chassi.
Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar a função pandas "str" para extrair os últimos 8 dígitos da coluna "chassi". Por exemplo:

```
//exemplo de dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'chassi': ['1234567890123456', '2345678901234567', '3456789012345678']})

//criar nova coluna com os últimos 8 dígitos do chassi
df['ultimos_8_digitos'] = df['chassi'].str[-8:]

//mostrar dataframe 
print(df)
```

O resultado será:

```
     chassi             ultimos_8_digitos
0  1234567890123456          90123456
1  2345678990123456          90123456
2  3456789012345678          12345678
```

Comment: Cara deu certo!!! Faz umas 5 horas que estou tentando fazer. 
Vlwwww